# documentation of typescript code

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

my question is rather short:

How do I document typescript code properly?
I found out that for projects becoming bigger and bigger, it is important to look at a function and immediately know parameters, what it returns and side-effects etc. It is tiring to have just a bunch of comments before a function, most of the time these 'blocks' even look differently in style. What I am looking for is a documentation tool like javadoc or doxygen for typescript. Is there anything out there? Or is it possible to 'abuse' a documentation tool and get it to work with typescript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687061/is-there-already-support-for-xml-documentation-inside-typescript

Comment: Already saw that one, but I wanted to know whether there is any working solution yet to create a real documentation. The "raw" comment-blocks are exactly what I try to avoid :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for something like JavaDoc, you might find JsDoc useful.

I have written a small tool for converting JsDoc comments in TypeScript definition files into JavaDoc-style HTML pages with links between types.

You can find it here, but right now it needs be built from source:

[typescript-docs](http://functorial.com/typescript-docs/)